# makefile with two rules for the same target

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile to create a library, and I need it to create a 80% library or a complete library, which means a library with 80% of the functions or a library with all of the functions.

When I call make, the "all" rule should create the 80% library (so far so good), and when I call "make complete" the "complete" rule should create the 100% library (still easy), and it should not relink in any case, here I have a problem.

**WHAT GOES WELL:**

here is what I have :

```
all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJS)
    ar -rc $@ $^

complete: $(NAME) $(MORE_OBJS)
    ar -rc $^

%.o : %.c
    gcc -I. -c -o $@ $<

.PHONY: complete
```

so if I run make it goes:

```
>make
gcc -I. -c -o function01.o function01.c
gcc -I. -c -o function02.o function02.c
gcc -I. -c -o function03.o function03.c
gcc -I. -c -o function04.o function04.c
ar -rc libtest.a function01.o function02.o function03.o function04.o
```

and make again:

```
>make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

perfect. then with make complete:

```
>make complete
gcc -I. -c -o function_05.o function05.c
gcc -I. -c -o function_06.o function06.c
ar -rc libtest.a function05.o function06.o
```

or of course:

```
>make fclean
rm *.o
rm libtest.a
>make complete
gcc -I. -c -o function01.o function01.c
gcc -I. -c -o function02.o function02.c
gcc -I. -c -o function03.o function03.c
gcc -I. -c -o function04.o function04.c
ar -rc libtest.a function01.o function02.o function03.o function04.o
gcc -I. -c -o function_05.o function05.c
gcc -I. -c -o function_06.o function06.c
ar -rc libtest.a function05.o function06.o
```

**WHAT GOES WRONG:**

but if I prompt make complete again:

```
>make complete
ar -rc libtest.a function05.o function06.o
```

I don't recompile but I relink the library.

I've tried a lot of approach, with the target-specific assignment, re-ordering the targets and the rules in many different combination, but I didn't find any way of doing it. am I missing something or is it indeed hard?

also, I can't put the additional functions in another file with its own makefile and use "make -C" to make it and then add it to the library, everything has to be in this makefile and the sources at the root

Comment: As @MadScientist wrote, `make` is not designed for having several recipes modifying the same target.  You can sometimes more or less work-around that, but rarely without adverse effects (like issues when trying to use `-j`).  At least gnu make has a notion of archive members as targets and dependencies, you can perhaps use it for your purpose (but IIRC, that feature has issue with `-j`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`make complete` will always run, because the target name is `complete` and no file named `complete` is ever created.  So as far as `make` knows that file is not up to date and needs to be rebuilt.

There is no straightforward way to do this because `make` doesn't support multiple different recipes creating the same target.

You can fake it out by using a sentinel file to inform make whether the target exists or not.  To do this, you need to create the file `complete` so make can use it to track whether or not it needs to be rebuilt.  Try:

```
complete: $(NAME) $(MORE_OBJS)
        ar -rc $^
        @touch $@
```

Comment: And `complete` should not be a `.PHONY` target.

Comment: it works of course if i delete ```complete``` from ```.PHONY``` but it's a workaround, i hoped there was something more clean ? I'm currently looking at the option -M of gcc because someone told me it could be a way, but i don't know what he meant so far :p

Comment: plus, there is a limit to this : if i want to go further and do it two times, first ```make``` 60%, ```make more``` 80%, and ```make complete``` 100%, when i run ```make coomplete``` first time it will run the rule ```more``` and then the rule ```complete```, so ```complete``` will modify ```$(name)``` more recently than ```more```, and so ```more``` will rerun... to avoid that i can put ```touch more complete``` in the rule ```complete``` but it's really not clean :/

Comment: What?  No, you have `complete : more $(NAME) $(MORE_OBJS)` then its `touch $@` will create `complete`, before that it will build the `more` target which has its own `touch $@` which will create the `more` file.

Comment: However, the basic answer is that no, there's nothing "more clean".  Make's fundamental design is to build targets, which relate to a file on the disk, and have a single recipe to build each target.  There's no simple way to have the same target built multiple times with different recipes depending on which one is asked for on the command line.  I have no idea what `gcc -M` would possibly do to help so I think that recommendation might be confused about what you want to do.  Or else I am :)

Comment: ok thanks it will do the trick ! but i assure you on my computer anyway it relink one time if i don't touch both ```more``` and ```complete``` in the ```complete``` rule, and i think it's because ```$(NAME)``` has been rebuilt so more recently modified

Comment: Hm.  Yes, the problem is likely because you're using the actual target for one of these.  You should use a sentinel for all three, like `base`, `more`, `complete`, then have `more : base` rather than `more: $(NAME)`.  Then you can add a `$(NAME): base` to allow the library to be built as a base library if neither `more` nor `complete` are specified.